# Spark error when accessing an empty or null array

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark

I have a JSON file with this type of schema:

```
{
 "name" : "john doe",
 "phone-numbers" : {
   "home": ["1111", "222"],
   "country" : "England" 
  }
}
```

The home phone numbers array could sometimes be empty.

My spark application receives a list of these JSONS and does this:

```
val dataframe = spark.read.json(filePaths: _*)
val result = dataframe.select($"name", 
                               explode(dataframe.col("phone-numbers.home")))
```

When the 'home' array is empty, I receive the following error when I try to explode it:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   '`phone-numbers`['home']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2
>   requires integral type, however, ''home'' is of string type.;;

Is there an elegant way to prevent spark from exploding this field if it's empty or null?

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Comment: What would you want to have as a result of no or empty home numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are not empty arrays (`"home" : []`) but arrays which are null (`"home" : null`) which do not work with `explode`

So either filter the null-values first:

```
val result = df
   .filter($"phone-numbers.home".isNotNull)
   .select($"name", explode($"phone-numbers.home"))
```

or replace the null-values with an empty array (which I would prefer in your situaion):

```
val nullToEmptyArr = udf(
   (arr:Array[Long]) => if(arr==null) Array.empty[Long] else arr
)

val result = df
  .withColumn("phone-numbers.home",nullToEmptyArr($"phone-numbers.home")) // clean existing column
  .select($"name", explode($"phone-numbers.home"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In spark there's a class called [`DataFrameNaFunctions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions), this class is specialized for working with missing data in `DataFrame`s.

this class contains three essentials method : `drop`, `replace` and `fill`

to use this methods the only thing that you have to do is to call the `df.na` method wich return a `DataFrameNaFunctions` for your `df` then apply one of the three method which returns your `df` with the specified operation.

to resolve your problem you can use something like that :

```
val dataframe = spark.read.json(filePaths: _*)
val result = dataframe.na.drop().select("name", 
                           explode(dataframe.col("phone-numbers.home")))
```

Hope this help, Best Regards